# How to display a null date in a Net Core view

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a model with date type properties that can be null

```
[Display(Name = "Vig. Conf.")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, NullDisplayText = "-")]
public DateTime? VigenciaConfeccion
{
    get => _vigenciaConfeccion;
    set
    {
        if (_vigenciaConfeccion != value)
        {
            _vigenciaConfeccion = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(VigenciaConfeccion));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the view that where the error is generated in the format of the three date labels.

```
@model WebProcesoTela.Models.VDiagramaDetailModel

@{
    // ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
    Layout = null;
}

<div class = "container-fluid">
    <h2>Detalle del renglón</h2>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="DiagramaId" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DiagramaId)</label>
            <input asp-for="DiagramaId" class="form-control text-center" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="DiagramaDetailId" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DiagramaDetailId)</label>
            <input asp-for="DiagramaDetailId" class="form-control text-center" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label asp-for="CompradorName" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CompradorName)</label>
            <input asp-for="CompradorName" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="ClaveLinea" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClaveLinea)</label>
            <input asp-for="ClaveLinea" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="VigenciaBonmoro" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VigenciaBonmoro)</label>
            <input type="date" asp-for="VigenciaBonmoro" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="VigenciaBannio" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VigenciaBannio)</label>
            <input type="date" asp-for="VigenciaBannio" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="VigenciaConfeccion" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VigenciaConfeccion)</label>
            <input type="date" asp-for="VigenciaConfeccion" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <label asp-for="ComentariosTejido" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ComentariosTejido)</label>
            <input asp-for="ComentariosTejido" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="FolioTejido" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FolioTejido)</label>
            <input asp-for="FolioTejido" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="FolioTejedor" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FolioTejedor)</label>
            <input asp-for="FolioTejedor" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="Bannio" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Bannio)</label>
            <input asp-for="Bannio" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label asp-for="TejedorName" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TejedorName)</label>
            <input asp-for="TejedorName" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label asp-for="AcabadorName" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AcabadorName)</label>
            <input asp-for="AcabadorName" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label asp-for="DeptoCategoriaName" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DeptoCategoriaName)</label>
            <input asp-for="DeptoCategoriaName" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="PedidoInterno" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PedidoInterno)</label>
            <input asp-for="PedidoInterno" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="ModeloId" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModeloId)</label>
            <input asp-for="ModeloId" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label asp-for="PiezaName" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PiezaName)</label>
            <input asp-for="PiezaName" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="Variante" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Variante)</label>
            <input asp-for="Variante" class="form-control text-center" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="TipoFondoName" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TipoFondoName)</label>
            <input asp-for="TipoFondoName" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label asp-for="ColorName" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ColorName)</label>
            <input asp-for="ColorName" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="CodigoColorProv" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CodigoColorProv)</label>
            <input asp-for="CodigoColorProv" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label asp-for="TipoCuelloName" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TipoCuelloName)</label>
            <input asp-for="TipoCuelloName" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="GpoCodigoTallaName" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GpoCodigoTallaName)</label>
            <input asp-for="GpoCodigoTallaName" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="TotalPiezas" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalPiezas)</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="TotalPiezas" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <label asp-for="TelaNameDD" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TelaNameDD)</label>
            <input asp-for="TelaNameDD" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="EstampadoId" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EstampadoId)</label>
            <input asp-for="EstampadoId" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label asp-for="EstampadoName" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EstampadoName)</label>
            <input asp-for="EstampadoName" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label asp-for="EstampadoEspecificacion" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EstampadoEspecificacion)</label>
            <input asp-for="EstampadoEspecificacion" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="CodigoEstampado" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CodigoEstampado)</label>
            <input asp-for="CodigoEstampado" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label asp-for="HilanderoName" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HilanderoName)</label>
            <input asp-for="HilanderoName" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label asp-for="HiloNameDD" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HiloNameDD)</label>
            <input asp-for="HiloNameDD" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label asp-for="HiloComposicion" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HiloComposicion)</label>
            <input asp-for="HiloComposicion" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="HiloGrsMt2" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HiloGrsMt2)</label>
            <input asp-for="HiloGrsMt2" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label asp-for="TejidoEspecificacion" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TejidoEspecificacion)</label>
            <input asp-for="TejidoEspecificacion" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="TelaAcabadoName" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TelaAcabadoName)</label>
            <input asp-for="TelaAcabadoName" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <label asp-for="Nota" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nota)</label>
            <input asp-for="Nota" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-6">
            <label asp-for="TotalTelaKilos" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalTelaKilos)</label>
            <input asp-for="TotalTelaKilos" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="TotalTelaMetros" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalTelaMetros)</label>
            <input asp-for="TotalTelaMetros" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label asp-for="TotalTelaKgsSinMerma" class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalTelaKgsSinMerma)</label>
            <input asp-for="TotalTelaKgsSinMerma" class="form-control" readonly disabled/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>

</div>
<hr />
<div class="form-group">
    <!-- Barra de Botones Details Modal -Regresar- -->
    <partial name="~/Views/Shared/Controls/_BtnsDetailsModal.cshtml"/>
</div>
```

When I load the view and the date is null, the "Input tag" shows "dd/MM/yyyy"

[image]

The editor asks me to put more details, but I don't know what else to put, since the problem is very simple.

The "input" tags display "dd/mm/yyyy" when the field is null.
What can I do so that it doesn't show me anything?

Comment: Could you share the code of your view?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to change the style of the date input. Using onfocu and onblur action

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="VigenciaConfeccion" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="VigenciaConfeccion" class="form-control" onfocus="(this.style.color='#000')" onblur="if(!this.value)this.style.color='transparent'" />
    <span asp-validation-for="VigenciaConfeccion" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#VigenciaConfeccion").focus();
        $("#VigenciaConfeccion").blur();
    </script>
}
```